# How to subscribe to changes for a public database in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, database, cloudkit

What is the best way to subscribe to a public database in CloudKit?
I have a table with persons. Every person contains a name and a location.
Once the location changes, the location is updated in CloudKit.
That part is working fine.

But I am not able to make it work to get a notification when there is a record update.

Some example would be really helpful, as I have looked into the possible option already.
I have looked into the options where I save the subscription in the database and also the CKModifySubscriptionsOperation option.

Currently, my code to subscribe looks like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
let newSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Person", predicate: predicate, options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordDeletion, .firesOnRecordUpdate])
let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
newSubscription.notificationInfo = info

database.save(newSubscription, completionHandler: {
      (subscription, error) in
      if error != nil {
          print("Error Creating Subscription")
          print(error)
      } else {
          userSettings.set(true, forKey: "subscriptionSaved")
      }
})
```

Can someone also show me how my AppDelegate should look like?

I have added the didReceiveRemoteNotification function to my AppDelegate. I also called application.registerForRemoteNotifications(). This is how my didReceiveRemoteNotification function looks like:
The print is not even coming for me.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Notification!!")

    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo) as? CKDatabaseNotification
    if notification != nil {
        AppData.checkUpdates(finishClosure: {(result) in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completionHandler(result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not someone that is just going to stackoverflow and randomly asks a question. I have done proper research on stackoverflow and other websites and also read CloudKit part in the iBook about IOS12 swift development. Until now without any result.

Comment: One question. Is it possible at all to subscribe for notifications of a public database?;) This works only for private and shared, but not public. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few other things you can check:

**= 1 =**

Make sure the CloudKit container defined in your code is the same one you are accessing in the CloudKit dashboard. Sometimes we overlook what we selected in Xcode as the CloudKit container when we create and test multiple containers.

**= 2 =**

Check the **Subscriptions** tab in the CloudKit dashboard and make sure your `Person` subscription is being created when you launch your app. If you see it, try deleting it in the CK Dashboard and then run your app again and make sure it shows up again.

**= 3 =**

Check the logs in the CK Dashboard. They will show a log entry of type `push` whenever a push notification is sent. If it's logging it when you update/add a record in the CK Dashboard, then you know the issue lies with your device.

**= 4 =**

Remember that push notifications don't work in the iOS simulator. You need an actual device (or a Mac if you are making a macOS app).

**= 5 =**

Through extensive testing, I've found notifications are more reliable if you always set the `alertBody` even if it's blank. Like this:

```
let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
info.alertBody = "" //This needs to be set or pushes don't always get sent
subscription.notificationInfo = info
```

**= 6 =**

For an iOS app, my app delegate handles notifications like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Ask Permission for Notifications
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { authorized, error in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if authorized {
          UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
      }
    })

    return true
  }

  //MARK: Background & Push Notifications
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]{
    let dict = userInfo as! [String: NSObject]
    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: dict)

    if let sub = notification.subscriptionID{
      print("iOS Notification: \(sub)")
    }
  }

  //After we get permission, register the user push notifications
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    //Add your CloudKit subscriptions here...
  }

}
```

Getting permission for notifications isn't required if you are only doing background pushes, but for anything the user sees in the form of a popup notification, you must get permission. If your app isn't asking for that permission, try deleting it off your device and building again in Xcode.

Good luck! : )

Comment: Thanks!! This did the trick for me. I was using the iPhone simulator (point 4), after I used my real iPhone, it started receiving the notifications. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PetervanLeeuwen:  Hi Peter.  I'm trying to do almost the exact thing you described in your question.  Can you point me to any books, articles, or links that helped you understand how to setup & subscribe CloudKit notifications?  Currently, I have been able to successfully save, edit and delete data in a simple List on public CloudKit on one device.  But any changes I make on one device does not automatically refresh on the other device until I restart the App or manually create a refresh button.  I appreciate if you can point me to resources that helped you solved your problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [RxCloudKit](https://github.com/maxvol/RxCloudKit) library, here's an a code snippet of how it handles query notifications -

```html
public func applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  let dict = userInfo as! [String: NSObject]
  let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: dict)
        
  switch notification.notificationType {
  case CKNotificationType.query:
    let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification
    self.delegate.query(notification: queryNotification, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
...
```

This method is called from `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`

Before you can receive notifications, you will need to do the following -

```html
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()        
...
```

**UPDATE:**
`Info.plist` should contain the following -

```html
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>fetch</string>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I have updated my question so you can see what my current status is. I have tried the things you suggested already.

Comment: What about `Info.plist`? Does it include <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fetch</string>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
 </array>

Comment: It does contain those values

Comment: Can you see the query subscription in CloudKit dashboard when logged in under the same account that was used to create subscription?

Comment: Yes that subscription is there.

Comment: Is "Push Notifications" enabled in "Capabilities"?

Comment: Yes, that is also enabled automatically after I enabled cloudkit

Comment: Make sure your app gets push notifications in general, like via APNS. Check whether the AppDelegate methods you override still have the same signature - this is often the reason something is not getting called when expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: As Reinhard mentioned in his comment: you can in fact still subscribe to changes from the public database and manually import the changes into Core Data. Still I am unsure whether it is a good idea to rely on subscriptions in the public database if Apple specifically mentioned these differences

**Original answer:**

I don't think the accepted answer fully answers the question here.
Short answer would be that the CloudKit public database does not support subscriptions like the private database. Instead only a polling mechanism can be used. `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` handles this automatically, but only updates very rarely.

[image]

This talk from WWDC2020 explains this in detail and I recommend watching it because there are other important details mentioned where public database differs from private database: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10650

In the talk they mentioned thet a pull is initiated on each app start and after about 30 mins of application usage.

Comment: Thanks for your comment after so much time! :)

Comment: Yea just stumbled over the same issues you had and wasted hours troubleshooting here. It probably won't help you anymore but maybe others ;)

Comment: Sorry, you are not correct: The CloudKit public database **does** support subscriptions. In the WWDC video that you cited, they say that a local CoreData database is updated by polling. What they did not say is that you can **additionally** subscribe to changes in the public iCloud database and you will receive push notifications after changes. Then it is up to you to update CoreData with the information pushed. I do this in my app and it works without problems.

Comment: Very interesting thank you, I was not aware of that. Though I am unsure whether this behavior will stay that way and continue to work in the future if they explicitly mention the differences in their talk.

Comment: Actually, they said that CoreData+CloudKit with a public database does not use push notifications but polling to update CoreData when iCloud changes. Maybe the reason is that it is not necessary to be logged in to iCloud in order to read public data. But if you are logged in, you can write a subscription record and receive push notifications after changes.

Comment: In https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabasesubscription it says: Only private and shared databases support database subscriptions. If you attempt to save a database subscription in the public database, CloudKit returns an error.